# Проблема при создании класса (Android)

Tags: xml, eclipse, android, java, классы

Впервые создаю собственный класс. При обращении к нему приложение вылетает. Помогите найти проблему, я, наверное, что-то не так по неопытности делаю. Назначение класса: должен активировать или деактивировать прокрутку, модификация ScrollView.
Создал новый файл в папке src/com.packagename с именем LockableScrollView.java:

```
package com.packagename;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

class LockableScrollView extends ScrollView {

public LockableScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

  private boolean mScrollable = true;

  public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
      mScrollable = enabled;
  }

  public boolean isScrollable() {
      return mScrollable;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      switch (ev.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              if (mScrollable) return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
              return mScrollable; // mScrollable is always false at this point
          default:
              return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
      }
  }
  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
      if (!mScrollable) return false;
      else return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
  }
}
```

В xml пишу

```
<com.packagename.LockableScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    ...
    ...
</com.packagename.LockableScrollView>
```

В коде при создании activity обращаюсь к классу, чтобы запретить прокрутку:

```
((LockableScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll)).setScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Ошибок Eclipse не находит, но при вызове этого activity выскакивает сообщение о том, что приложение остановлено. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: может быть, можно запустить вылетающий код под отладчиком? или добавить логирование/отладочную печать, чтобы локализовать проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась после добавления в код класса

```
LockableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

и

```
LockableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle):
```

Получилось:

```
class LockableScrollView extends ScrollView {

public LockableScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
public LockableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);

}
public LockableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

Comment: Закройте пожалуйста вопрос если правильно на него ответили.

Comment: Что-то не могу найти кнопку "закрыть". Только править и удалить...